# How to call an existing payment methods in the registration form?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, registration

When a customer registers it is necessary that he chooses one of the payment methods that are enabled from the admin panel, someone can help, at least give directions to solving this task, thanks

(i have enabled two methods - credit cards  and check )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that give you current active payment method from admin.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Block;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Model\Config;

class Paymentmethods extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $paymentmodelconfig;  

    public function __construct(Config $paymentmodelconfig, ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig){
        $this->paymentmodelconfig = $paymentmodelconfig;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function getActivePaymentMethod()
    {
        $payments = $this->paymentmodelconfig->getActiveMethods();
        $methods = array();
        foreach ($payments as $paymentCode => $paymentModel)
        {
            $paymentTitle = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
            $methods[$paymentCode] = array(
                'label' => $paymentTitle,
                'value' => $paymentCode
            );
        }
        return $methods;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dhiren Vasoya, it's give an error , Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function dispatch() on null in

Comment: i updated construct and it works, thanks

Comment: if answer help you, upvote and accepted as solution. So it help other in community.